# Compare two arrays of objects (given the objects have same props, but not values)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider below two arrays of objects:

```
const arr1 = [
  {name: "name1", id: 1},
  {name: "name2", id: 2},
  {name: "name3", id: 3}
];

const arr2 = [
  {name: "name1", id: 1},
  {name: "name2", id: 4},
  {name: "name3", id: 3}
];
```

Comparison of these two objects must return `false` because there are values for prop `id` in `arr2` that are missing in `arr1` (namely `id: 4`).

At this point, the below attempt has been made:

```
arr1.every(i => i.id === arr2.map(z =>z.id));
```

NOTE:
Suppose `arr2` was:

```
const arr2 = [
    {name: "name1", id: 1},
    {name: "name3", id: 3}
];
```

The comparison must return `true`, since the `id` of every element in `arr2` is found in `arr1`'s elements.

Comment: `arr1.every(i => arr2.map(z => z.id).includes(i.id))` <--- please try this & share feedback.

Comment: There has to be a good original question to point this at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're relaly close, but `map` is for mapping each element of the array to some new value, not for seeing if an element exists. You'd use `some` for that, and you'd want to reverse the arrays you're calling `every` and `some` on:

```
const flag = arr2.every(element => arr1.some(({id}) => id === element.id));
```

That says: "Does every element of `arr2` have at least one matching element in `arr1` by `id`?"

Live Example:

```js
const arr1 = [
    {name: "name1", id: 1},
    {name: "name2", id: 2},
    {name: "name3", id: 3}
];

const arr2 = [
    {name: "name1", id: 1},
    {name: "name2", id: 4},
    {name: "name3", id: 3}
];

const arr3 = [
    {name: "name1", id: 1},
    {name: "name3", id: 3}
];

const result1 = arr2.every(element => arr1.some(({id}) => id === element.id));
console.log("arr2 and arr1: " + result1);

const result2 = arr3.every(element => arr1.some(({id}) => id === element.id));
console.log("arr3 and arr1: " + result2);
```

Comment: Very elegant !! May be the other way around is also required. This checks if every `arr1` element is present in `arr2`. May be the OP also requires to check if every `arr2` element is present in `arr1` too?

Comment: @jsN00b - Actually, I had it the wrong way around to start with. :-) Noticed when I did the live example.